# How do i console log the results inside the subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, console

In my angular app i am calling a service and fetching the data, i need to add a console log once the results are fetched. where can i add console log?

```
 this.searchTerm.asObservable()
            .debounceTime(300)      
            .distinctUntilChanged() 
            .switchMap(term => this.doFind(term))
            .subscribe(data => this.results = data
            , error => {
                this.errorMessage = error;
            });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a code block

```
this.searchTerm.asObservable()
        .debounceTime(300)      
        .distinctUntilChanged() 
        .switchMap(term => this.doFind(term))
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.results = data;
           console.log('data', data);
        })
        , error => {
            this.errorMessage = error;
        });
```

or the `do` operator

```
 this.searchTerm.asObservable()
        .debounceTime(300)      
        .distinctUntilChanged() 
        .switchMap(term => this.doFind(term))
        .do(val => condole.log(val))
        .subscribe(data => this.results = data
        , error => {
            this.errorMessage = error;
        });
```

Comment: .do(this.resultFetched == true); i cannot do this

Comment: I didn't say you should ;-) What would you want to do this for?

Comment: i want to assign to a variable to true when the results are fetched

Comment: Ok, but that is in no way related to your original question. Why don't you do it in `subscribe`? `do` is intended to be used only for its side effects which seems a good fit for logging.

Comment: then where to set it? i need to set it once i get the results. actually i have put console.log in the question, instead i need to set the variable to true

Comment: As I said, why don't you do it in `subscribe`?

Comment: can you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633995/close-the-following-dropdown-when-user-click-outside

Comment: Didn't you just previously post a link to a similar question with several answers?

Comment: yes i did, thats the link attached in the question. any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the shorthand version of the arrow function, use the bigger version :)

```
.subscribe((data) => {
     this.results = data;
     console.log(data);
 }, error => {
    this.errorMessage = error;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

u can do like this

```
  this.searchTerm.asObservable()
        .debounceTime(300)      
        .distinctUntilChanged() 
        .switchMap(term => this.doFind(term))
        .subscribe(
            data=>this.message=data.msg,
            error=>alert('errer'),
            ()=>{console.log('finished');}

            );
```