# http get request returning undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am running in an Ionic/Angular environment 
I am trying to do a simple get request using HttpClient 
my code is as follows :

```
  ngOnInit(){
this.userprovider.getUsers()
  .subscribe(users => this.users = users, 
    errmess => this.userErrMess = <any>errmess);
  console.log(this.users);
 }
```

my getUsers function looks like this

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
return this.http.get<User[]>(baseURL + 'users')
  .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
 .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

my console log looks like this

```
profile.ts:44 - undefined

user.ts:30 - All: [{"id":0,"featured":true,"username":"Jackie","password":"password","birthday":"Oct 1, 1994","numkids":2,"profileImg":"images/jackie.jpg","description":"Description goes here","pics":[{"image":"/public/images/jackie.jpg","description":"Description goes here","numLikes":24,"numFavs":3,"comments":[{"description":"Description goes here","author":"user1","date":"Today"},{"description":"Description goes here","author":"user1","date":"Today"}]}],"feed":[{"description":"My first update!","numLikes":12,"numFavs":1,"comments":[{"description":"Description goes here","author":"user1","date":"Today"}],"date":"Today"}],"messages":[],"startDate":"Yesterday","numFriends":28,"numMombo":4}]
```

I know that I am able to retrieve JSON data because I am able to log it to the console. However, it seems that in ngOnInit when I call the getUser function it is returning undefined. I cannot find an answer as to why this is returning undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i console log the results inside the subscribe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628493/how-do-i-console-log-the-results-inside-the-subscribe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add the console log inside the `subscribe`. since javascript is asynchronous, it does not wait until the `XHR` response. it keeps on executing. that is why console print undefined. Because at that time response is not assign to `users` variable.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.userprovider.getUsers()
          .subscribe((users) => {
                  this.users = users
                  console.log(this.users);
              },
              errmess => this.userErrMess = < any > errmess);
  }
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you so much! I have to wait a few minutes before I can mark this as the answer, but I will when it lets me

Comment: this is not related to the question you answered (or it might be!), however, I was able to get all my information from API minus my image. I have checked the error log and it is showing error 404 not found. I notice that it is directing to the correct location except that there is an unknown property in the file directory? example: should be localhost:3000/images/image.jpg but I am showing localhost:3000/*undefined*images/image.jpg. Do you have any idea why this would be showing?